# How to call a stored procedure from Java and JPA

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, jpa, jboss

I am writing a simple web application to call a stored procedure and retrieve some data.
Its a very simple application, which interacts with client's database. We pass employee id and company id and the stored procedure will return employee details.

Web application cannot update/delete data and is using SQL Server.

I am deploying my web application in Jboss AS. Should I use JPA to access the stored procedure or `CallableStatement`. Any advantage of using JPA in this case.

Also what will be the sql statement to call this stored procedure. I have never used stored procedures before and I am struggling with this one. Google was not much of a help.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE procedure getEmployeeDetails (@employeeId int, @companyId int)
as
begin
    select firstName, 
           lastName, 
           gender, 
           address
      from employee et
     where et.employeeId = @employeeId
       and et.companyId = @companyId
end
```

Update:

For anyone else having problem calling stored procedure using *JPA*.

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("{call getEmployeeDetails(?,?)}",
                                   EmployeeDetails.class)           
                                   .setParameter(1, employeeId)
                                   .setParameter(2, companyId);

List<EmployeeDetails> result = query.getResultList();
```

Things I have noticed:

1. Parameter names didn't work for me, so try using parameter index.
2. Correct sql statement `{call sp_name(?,?)}` instead of  `call sp_name(?,?)`
3. If stored procedure is returning a result set, even if you know with only one row, `getSingleResult` wont work
4. Pass a `resultSetMapping` name or result class details

Comment: You cannot use named parameters in *native* queries. Named parameters are supported only for JPQL queries. (If you prefer named parameters, you could write your own class to translate named to numbered parameters.)

Comment: I've always used named parameters with createNativeQueries and never had any problem. I've just took a look at the current system I've been working and there's tons of native queries with named parameters. Can you provide us some reference for your affirmation? Our set is JPA 2 and Hibernate 4+.

Answer (score 67):

JPA 2.1 now support Stored Procedure, read the Java doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createStoredProcedureQuery%28java.lang.String%29).

Example:

```
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("sales_tax");
// set parameters
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("subtotal", Double.class, ParameterMode.IN);
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("tax", Double.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
storedProcedure.setParameter("subtotal", 1f);
// execute SP
storedProcedure.execute();
// get result
Double tax = (Double)storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("tax");
```

See detailed example [here](http://dreamand.me/java/java-jee7-jpa-stored-procedure-example/).

Comment: Example works with a function, not a stored procedure

Comment: This worked for me. It worked for an Oracle stored procedure

Comment: You can also daisy chain all the configurations and call execute at the end to make it less verbose.. calling storedProcedure each time

Answer (score 23):

> I am deploying my web application in Jboss AS. Should I use JPA to access the stored procedure or CallableStatement. Any advantage of using JPA in this case.

It is not really supported by JPA but it's [doable](https://web.archive.org/web/20160326061539/http://objectopia.com/2009/06/26/calling-stored-procedures-in-jpa/). Still I wouldn't go this way:

- using JPA just to map the result of a stored procedure call in some beans is really overkill,
- especially given that JPA is not really appropriate to call stored procedure (the syntax will be pretty verbose).

I would thus rather consider using [Spring support for JDBC data access](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html), or a data mapper like [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/java.html) or, given the simplicity of your application, raw JDBC and `CallableStatement`. Actually, JDBC would probably be my choice. Here is a basic kickoff example:

```
CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call getEmployeeDetails(?, ?)}");
cstmt.setInt("employeeId", 123);
cstmt.setInt("companyId", 456);
ResultSet rs = cstmt.executeQuery();
```

#### Reference

- JDBC documentation: [Java SE 6](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/)

Comment: As stated in the [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18555770/281545) it is supported - you might want to edit

Answer (score 13):

1. For a simple stored procedure that using IN/OUT parameters like this

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE count_comments (  
      postId IN NUMBER,  
      commentCount OUT NUMBER )  
   AS 
   BEGIN 
       SELECT COUNT(*) INTO commentCount  
       FROM post_comment  
       WHERE post_id = postId; 
   END;
   ```

   You can call it from JPA as follows:

   ```
   StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
       .createStoredProcedureQuery("count_comments")
       .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Long.class, 
           ParameterMode.IN)
       .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, Long.class, 
           ParameterMode.OUT)
       .setParameter(1, 1L);

   query.execute();

   Long commentCount = (Long) query.getOutputParameterValue(2);
   ```
2. For a stored procedure which uses a `SYS_REFCURSOR` OUT parameter:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE post_comments ( 
      postId IN NUMBER, 
      postComments OUT SYS_REFCURSOR ) 
   AS 
   BEGIN
       OPEN postComments FOR
       SELECT *
       FROM post_comment 
       WHERE post_id = postId; 
   END;
   ```

   You can call it as follows:

   ```
   StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager
       .createStoredProcedureQuery("post_comments")
       .registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, Long.class, 
            ParameterMode.IN)
       .registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, Class.class, 
            ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)
       .setParameter(1, 1L);

   query.execute();

   List<Object[]> postComments = query.getResultList();
   ```
3. For a SQL function that looks as follows:

   ```
   CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_count_comments ( 
       postId IN NUMBER ) 
       RETURN NUMBER 
   IS
       commentCount NUMBER; 
   BEGIN
       SELECT COUNT(*) INTO commentCount 
       FROM post_comment 
       WHERE post_id = postId; 
       RETURN( commentCount ); 
   END;
   ```

   You can call it like this:

   ```
   BigDecimal commentCount = (BigDecimal) entityManager
   .createNativeQuery(
       "SELECT fn_count_comments(:postId) FROM DUAL"
   )
   .setParameter("postId", 1L)
   .getSingleResult();
   ```

   At least when using Hibernate 4.x and 5.x because the JPA `StoredProcedureQuery` does not work for SQL FUNCTIONS.

For more details about how to call stored procedures and functions when using JPA and Hibernate, check out the following articles

- [How to call Oracle stored procedures and functions with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedures-and-functions-from-hibernate/)
- [How to call SQL Server stored procedures and functions with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-sql-server-stored-procedures-and-functions-from-hibernate/)
- [How to call PostgreSQL functions (stored procedures) with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-postgresql-functions-from-hibernate/)
- [How to call MySQL stored procedures and functions with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-mysql-stored-procedures-and-functions-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: I kept getting "wrong number or types of arguments in call to ..." error message. I realized that I was calling `createNativeQuery`. I switched to `createStoredProcedureQuery`. Then, voila!

Answer (score 11):

You need to pass the parameters to the stored procedure.

It should work like this:

```
    List result = em
      .createNativeQuery("call getEmployeeDetails(:employeeId,:companyId)")
      .setParameter("emplyoyeeId", 123L)
      .setParameter("companyId", 456L)
      .getResultList();
```

---

**Update:**

Or maybe it shouldn't.

In the Book [EJB3 in Action](http://www.manning.com/panda/), it says on page 383, that [JPA does not support stored procedures](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9781933988344/383) (page is only a preview, you don't get the full text, the entire book is available as a download in several places including [this one](http://scjp-preparacion.googlecode.com/files/Manning.EJB.3.in.Action.Apr.2007.pdf), I don't know if this is legal though).

Anyway, the text is this:

#### JPA and database stored procedures

> If you’re a big fan of SQL, you may be
> willing to exploit the power of
> database stored procedures.
> Unfortunately, JPA doesn’t support
> stored procedures, and you have to
> depend on a proprietary feature of
> your persistence provider. However,
> you can use simple stored functions
> (without out parameters) with a native
> SQL query.

Comment: I tried and getting this error message:

java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.

Comment: It should be "{call getEmployeeDetails(:employeeId,:companyId)}", for SQL server it has to have curly braces.

Comment: @Vedran true. I was only interested in the parameter setting part

Answer (score 9):

## How to retrieve Stored Procedure output parameter using JPA (2.0 needs EclipseLink imports and 2.1 does not)

Even though this answer does elaborate on returning a recordset from a stored procedure,
I am posting here, because it took me ages to figure it out and this thread helped me.

My application was using Eclipselink-2.3.1, but I will force an upgrade to
Eclipselink-2.5.0, as JPA 2.1 has much better support for stored procedures.

### Using EclipseLink-2.3.1/JPA-2.0: Implementation-Dependent

This method requires imports of EclipseLink classes from "org.eclipse.persistence", so it is specific to Eclipselink implementation.

I found it at "http://www.yenlo.nl/en/calling-oracle-stored-procedures-from-eclipselink-with-multiple-out-parameters".

```
StoredProcedureCall storedProcedureCall = new StoredProcedureCall();
storedProcedureCall.setProcedureName("mypackage.myprocedure");
storedProcedureCall.addNamedArgument("i_input_1"); // Add input argument name.
storedProcedureCall.addNamedOutputArgument("o_output_1"); // Add output parameter name.
DataReadQuery query = new DataReadQuery();
query.setCall(storedProcedureCall);
query.addArgument("i_input_1"); // Add input argument names (again);
List<Object> argumentValues = new ArrayList<Object>();
argumentValues.add("valueOf_i_input_1"); // Add input argument values.
JpaEntityManager jpaEntityManager = (JpaEntityManager) getEntityManager();
Session session = jpaEntityManager.getActiveSession();
List<?> results = (List<?>) session.executeQuery(query, argumentValues);
DatabaseRecord record = (DatabaseRecord) results.get(0);
String result = String.valueOf(record.get("o_output_1")); // Get output parameter
```

### Using EclipseLink-2.5.0/JPA-2.1: Implementation-Independent (documented already in this thread)

This method is implementation independent (don't need Eclipslink imports).

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = getEntityManager().createStoredProcedureQuery("mypackage.myprocedure");
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("i_input_1", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("o_output_1", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
query.setParameter("i_input_1", "valueOf_i_input_1");
boolean queryResult = query.execute();
String result = String.valueOf(query.getOutputParameterValue("o_output_1"));
```

Comment: Aah, my eyes hurt. This isn't really that much better than JDBC, is it?

Comment: Haha, yes point taken. However the benefit to using these things is that you don't have to type a load of code in to get the data object class and you don't have to do the bit where you transfer all the data from the recordSet into your data class. There's still a data object (Entity), but the Eclipse wizard generates it for you.

Comment: Yes, you could. But I'm saying this as the developer of [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org), where everything is generated. Only thing left to do is to actually call the procedure / function.

Comment: Did you actually try the bottom example(implementation independent)? I tried it with the difference that the procedure was defined in an `xml` file and it didn't work. I can't read the `OUT` parameter.

Comment: Somehow for the JPA - 2.1 Implementation, Named Parameters are not working for me. Instead, I had to pass their Position Index in the Stored Procedures and was successfully able to get the result for the Output Parameter. 

This was the case when I have Stored Procedure Returning Multiple Result Sets. For the 1 ResultSet I simply used @Query

Answer (score 6):

For me, only the following worked with Oracle 11g and Glassfish 2.1 (Toplink):

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("BEGIN PROCEDURE_NAME(); END;");
query.executeUpdate();
```

The variant with curly braces resulted in ORA-00900.

Comment: Works for me on Oracle 11g, hibernate JPA provider.

Comment: This got us out from an extremely huge trouble. We were using java6, oracle11g, Jboss6, Hibernate. Thanks @Chornyi.

Answer (score 6):

If using EclipseLink you can use the @NamedStoredProcedureQuery or StoreProcedureCall to execute any stored procedure, including ones with output parameters, or out cursors.  Support for stored functions and PLSQL data-types is also available.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Stored_Procedures

Comment: Which version of EclipseLink has the EntityManager.createNamedStoredProcedureQuery()?

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me:

```
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("BEGIN VALIDACIONES_QPAI.RECALC_COMP_ASSEMBLY('X','X','X',0); END;");
query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: OUT and INOUT parameters won't work using this API. See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Stored_Procedures_in_JPA_2.0

Answer (score 2):

May be it's not the same for Sql Srver but for people using oracle and eclipslink it's working for me

ex: a procedure that have one IN param (type CHAR) and two OUT params (NUMBER & VARCHAR)

in the persistence.xml  declare the persistence-unit :

```
<persistence-unit name="presistanceNameOfProc" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/DataSourceName</jta-data-source>
    <mapping-file>META-INF/eclipselink-orm.xml</mapping-file>
    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINEST"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.logger" value="DefaultLogger"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.ddl.table-creation-suffix" value="JPA_STORED_PROC" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

and declare the structure of the proc in the eclipselink-orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><entity-mappings version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_2_0.xsd">
<named-stored-procedure-query name="PERSIST_PROC_NAME" procedure-name="name_of_proc" returns-result-set="false">
    <parameter direction="IN" name="in_param_char" query-parameter="in_param_char" type="Character"/>
    <parameter direction="OUT" name="out_param_int" query-parameter="out_param_int" type="Integer"/>
    <parameter direction="OUT" name="out_param_varchar" query-parameter="out_param_varchar" type="String"/>
</named-stored-procedure-query>
```

in the code you just have to call your proc like this :

```
try {
        final Query query = this.entityManager
                .createNamedQuery("PERSIST_PROC_NAME");
        query.setParameter("in_param_char", 'V'); 
        resultQuery = (Object[]) query.getSingleResult();

    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        LOGGER.log(ex);
        throw new TechnicalException(ex);
    }
```

to get the two output params :

```
Integer myInt = (Integer) resultQuery[0];
String myStr =  (String) resultQuery[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="acct")
@NamedNativeQueries({
 @NamedNativeQuery(callable=true, name="Account.findOne", query="call sp_get_acct(?), resultClass=Account.class)})
public class Account{
 // Code 
}
```

Note : in future if you decide to use default version of findOne then just comment the NamedNativeQueries annotation and JPA will switch to default

Comment: If i want to call procedure within the specific package, should I call in this way : call {package}.{procedure}  ?

Answer (score 1):

This answer might be helpful if you have entity manager

I had a stored procedure to create next number and on server side I have seam framework.

Client side

```
 Object on = entityManager.createNativeQuery("EXEC getNextNmber").executeUpdate();
        log.info("New order id: " + on.toString());
```

Database Side (SQL server) I have stored procedure named `getNextNmber`

Comment: executeUpdate() return int. Are sure that you a receiving output of sproc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@Query(value = "{call PROC_TEST()}", nativeQuery = true)` in your repository. This worked for me.

**Attention:** use '{' and '}' or else it will not work.

Comment: How to pass a parameter?

Answer (score 1):

JPA 2.0 doesn't support RETURN values, only calls.

My solution was. Create a FUNCTION calling PROCEDURE.

So, inside JAVA code you execute a NATIVE QUERY calling the oracle FUNCTION.

Answer (score 1):

From JPA 2.1 , JPA supports to call stored procedures using the dynamic StoredProcedureQuery, and the declarative @NamedStoredProcedureQuery.

Answer (score 0):

To call stored procedure we can use Callable Statement in java.sql package.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So the sql for callable statement will be 

{ ? = call getEmployeeDetails (?,?) }

or need to specify all output parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
return em.createNativeQuery("{call getEmployeeDetails(?,?)}",
                               EmployeeDetails.class)           
                               .setParameter(1, employeeId)
                               .setParameter(2, companyId).getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

persistence.xml

```
 <persistence-unit name="PU2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
<non-jta-data-source>jndi_ws2</non-jta-data-source>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties/>
```

codigo java

```
  String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "PU2";
    EntityManagerFactory factory2;
    factory2 = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);

    EntityManager em2 = factory2.createEntityManager();
    boolean committed = false;
    try {

        try {
            StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em2.createStoredProcedureQuery("PKCREATURNO.INSERTATURNO");
            // set parameters
            storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("inuPKEMPRESA", BigDecimal.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("inuPKSERVICIO", BigDecimal.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("inuPKAREA", BigDecimal.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("isbCHSIGLA", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("INUSINCALIFICACION", BigInteger.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("INUTIMBRAR", BigInteger.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("INUTRANSFERIDO", BigInteger.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("INTESTADO", BigInteger.class, ParameterMode.IN);
            storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("inuContador", BigInteger.class, ParameterMode.OUT);

            BigDecimal inuPKEMPRESA = BigDecimal.valueOf(1);
            BigDecimal inuPKSERVICIO = BigDecimal.valueOf(5);
            BigDecimal inuPKAREA = BigDecimal.valueOf(23);
            String isbCHSIGLA = "";
            BigInteger INUSINCALIFICACION = BigInteger.ZERO;
            BigInteger INUTIMBRAR = BigInteger.ZERO;
            BigInteger INUTRANSFERIDO = BigInteger.ZERO;
            BigInteger INTESTADO = BigInteger.ZERO;
            BigInteger inuContador = BigInteger.ZERO;

            storedProcedure.setParameter("inuPKEMPRESA", inuPKEMPRESA);
            storedProcedure.setParameter("inuPKSERVICIO", inuPKSERVICIO);
            storedProcedure.setParameter("inuPKAREA", inuPKAREA);
            storedProcedure.setParameter("isbCHSIGLA", isbCHSIGLA);
            storedProcedure.setParameter("INUSINCALIFICACION", INUSINCALIFICACION);
            storedProcedure.setParameter("INUTIMBRAR", INUTIMBRAR);
            storedProcedure.setParameter("INUTRANSFERIDO", INUTRANSFERIDO);
            storedProcedure.setParameter("INTESTADO", INTESTADO);
            storedProcedure.setParameter("inuContador", inuContador);

            // execute SP
            storedProcedure.execute();
            // get result

            try {
                long _inuContador = (long) storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("inuContador");
                varCon = _inuContador + "";
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } 
        } finally {

        }
    } finally {
        em2.close();
    }
```

Comment: please, don't hesitate to add any comment to your answer (other than pure code).

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to use JpaRepository

```
1- Create a stored procedure
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getEmployeeDetails
(
@employeeId         int,
@companyId          int
)  AS
BEGIN
 SELECT firstName,lastName,gender,address
 FROM employee et
 WHERE et.employeeId = @employeeId and et.companyId = @companyId
END


2- Create Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class EmployeeDetails {
    @Id
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String gender;
    private String address;
 }


3- Create Repository
public interface EmployeeDetailsRepository extends 
JpaRepository<EmployeeDetails,String> {
@Query(value = "EXEC dbo.getEmployeeDetails @employeeId=:empId, 
                                          @companyId=:compId",nativeQuery =true)
List<EmployeeDetails> getEmployeeList(@Param("employeeId") Integer empId, 
                                      @Param("companyId") Integer compId);
}

4- create Controller
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/employee")
public class EmployeeController {

@Autowired
private EmployeeDetailsRepository empRepo;

@GetMapping(value = "/details")
public ResponseEntity<List<EmployeeDetails>> getEmployeeDetails(@RequestParam 
            String empId, @RequestParam String compId) {
try {
   List<EmployeeDetails> result = empRepo.getEmployeeList(
                                Integer.valueOf(empId),Integer.valueOf(compId));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED).body(null);
    }
}
}
```

you can now call http://localhost:8080/api/employee/details?empId=1&compId=25

Answer (score 0):

If you're not too attached to calling this particular procedure with JPA or JDBC, you could use [jOOQ, a third party library that generates stubs for all of your stored procedures](https://blog.jooq.org/the-best-way-to-call-stored-procedures-from-java-with-jooq/) to simplify calling them, and making the calls type safe.

#### Calling procedures returning unspecified cursors

In your particular case, the procedure returns an untyped, undeclared cursor (it could return several cursors and interleaved update counts). So, you could call the procedure like this with jOOQ:

```java
GetEmployeeDetails proc = new GetEmployeeDetails();
proc.setEmployeeId(1);
proc.setCompanyId(2);
proc.execute(configuration);

// Iterate over potentially multiple results
for (Result<?> result : proc.getResults()) {

    // Print the first result set (your employee query)
    System.out.println(result);

    // Use your implicit knowledge of the content of the query
    // Without type safety
    for (Record record : result) {

        // All tables / columns are also generated
        System.out.println("First name: " + record.get(EMPLOYEE.FIRSTNAME));
        System.out.println("Last name: " + record.get(EMPLOYEE.LASTNAME));
        System.out.println("Gender: " + record.get(EMPLOYEE.GENDER));
        System.out.println("Address: " + record.get(EMPLOYEE.ADDRESS));
    }
}
```

#### Using an actual table valued function, instead

Personally, I don't really like that feature of a few RDBMS (including SQL Server, MySQL) of returning arbitrary untyped cursors. Why not just declare the result type? SQL Server has powerful [table valued functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). E.g. just use this syntax here:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION getEmployeeDetails (@employeeId int, @companyId int)
RETURNS TABLE
AS RETURN
  SELECT
    firstName,
    lastName,
    gender,
    address
  FROM employee et
  WHERE et.employeeId = @employeeId
  AND et.companyId = @companyId
```

Now, you have the full type information associated with this function in your catalog, and if you're still using jOOQ, that information will be available to the code generator, so you can call the function like this:

```java
for (GetEmployeeDetailsRecord record : ctx.selectFrom(getEmployeeDetails(1, 2))) {
    System.out.println("First name: " + record.getFirstName());
    System.out.println("Last name: " + record.getLastName());
    System.out.println("Gender: " + record.getGender());
    System.out.println("Address: " + record.getAddress());
}
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ