# Calling an oracle function from JPA

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

I am trying to call a simple function from a JPA class that returns a number based on some calculations and has the following definition.

```
'CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION CFB.FC_AMOUNT_CHECK(accountNumber IN VARCHAR2)
return NUMBER IS .....'
```

I am trying to call this function from JPA the following way.

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("call CFB.FC_AMOUNT_CHECK(:accountNumber)");
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql.toString());
query.setParameter(1, '1234');
List<?> result = query.getResultList();
```

....

However, when I execute this class, I get the below exception all the time:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [1]
```

I cant seem to get how JPA cannot find parameter 1....I have been breaking my head with this for the last 4 hours. Can anyone please suggest how to get the result I want?

Comment: Never worked in Hibernate. Not sure: is this line right? `query.setParameter(1, '1234');`

Comment: Yes, that is a valid statement in JPA.

Comment: can you try `query.setParameter("accountNumber", '1234');` and let me know the result for me?

Comment: Also not sure why you want to use bind variable when you are replacing it with literals. If possible change this `"call CFB.FC_AMOUNT_CHECK(accountNumber)"` and then try `query.setParameter("accountNumber", '1234');`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling stored procedure from Java / JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572626/calling-stored-procedure-from-java-jpa)

Comment: have you tried with setting parameter value directly in sql as - "call CFB.FC_AMOUNT_CHECK("+accountNumber+")"

Comment: Yes Nayan - I tried to put in the value as you have suggested but with no luck. I think this is a fundamental problem with JPA and function calls. JPA seems to be lagging in terms of implementing a standard way of invoking SPs and functions in general.

Comment: I was able to call it, but without any in/out parameters, but no clue about to passing parameters.

Comment: As far as I know JPA doesn't support named parameters binding in native queries... you should stick to ? and indexed binding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a custom Oracle function returning a value from JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989263/how-to-call-a-custom-oracle-function-returning-a-value-from-jpa)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to call a function in JPA select query then follow below link, it works:

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/jpa/extensions/j_func.htm

Answer (score -1):

If you want to set query parameters by index:

```
query.setParameter(1, '1234');
```

You need to change the named parameters inside the query, and replace it with a `?`, like this:

```
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("call CFB.FC_AMOUNT_CHECK(?)");
```