# Spring Data JPA calling Oracle Function

Tags: java, spring, oracle, function, jpa

I am running an simple application that uses Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA for persistence.

Below is a sample Oracle function I would like to have the value returned at the Service implementation class.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PKG_TEST AS 
  FUNCTION HELLO_WORLD(TEXT VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2;
END PKG_TEST;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY PKG_TEST AS 
  FUNCTION HELLO_WORLD(TEXT VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN 'HELLO WORLD ' || TEXT;
  END;
END PKG_TEST;
```

Doing this with no framework would be simple, but the project is built into Spring Boot JPA, so it's better to use it.

I need a reference guide link or simple base structure to follow. 
I searched all over SO and Spring Data JPA reference and all examples I found are for CRUD and Stored Procedures, nothing for Functions.

I tried to use the Stored procedure example modified for function but didn't work.

Comment: I don't think there is support for sql functions, there are ways to call them but not to create and store them as far as I know.
The JPA specification hasn't such contract from the javadoc, I doubt it's being implemented by any persistence provider

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can call your function via native query and get result from dual.

```
public interface HelloWorldRepository extends JpaRepository<HelloWorld, Long> {

    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT PKG_TEST.HELLO_WORLD(:text) FROM dual")
    String callHelloWorld(@Param("text") String text);

}
```

Note that it won't work if your function is using DML statements. In this case you'll need to use `@Modifying` annotation over query, but then the function itself must return number due to `@Modifying` return type restrictions.

You can also implement your `CustomRepository` and use `SimpleJdbcCall`:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcCall;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public class HelloWorldRepositoryImpl implements HelloWorldRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public String callHelloWorld() {
        SimpleJdbcCall jdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                .withCatalogName("PKG_TEST") //package name
                .withFunctionName("HELLO_WORLD");
        SqlParameterSource paramMap = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("param", "value"));
        //First parameter is function output parameter type.
        return jdbcCall.executeFunction(String.class, paramMap));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Incase if you need to return a set of columns with n number of rows returned as a oracle type from a function, Use *Table(function_name)* with the select statement to parse the type as table and get as list of object array List.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM TABLE(ListOfStates(:country))")
List<Object[]> findStatesByCountry(@Param("country") String country);
```

Comment: What happens to this query if the ListOfStates function also takes an OUT parameter (let say myOutParam) please ??

Answer (score 0):

using entityManager.createNativeQuery works.

See: [How to call a custom Oracle function returning a value from JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989263/how-to-call-a-custom-oracle-function-returning-a-value-from-jpa)

and the referenced page: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedures-and-functions-from-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hibernate as JPA Provider you may create custom dialect and register needed function.

```
public class CustomDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {
    public CustomDialect() {
        super();
        // CustomFunction implements SqlFunction
        registerFunction("custom_function", new CustomFunction());
        // or use StandardSQLFunction; useful for coalesce
        registerFunction("coalesce", new StandardSQLFunction("coalesce"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface inteface-name extends CrudRepository<Object,Long> {

    @Procedure(procedureName = "procedure-name", outputParameterName = "param-out-name")
    BigDecimal method-name(dataType input-param);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.entityManager.getSession().doWork(connection -> {
        try (CallableStatement query = connection
                .prepareCall("BEGIN ? := FUNCTION_NAME(?); END;")) {
            query.registerOutParameter("PARAM1", Types.VARCHAR); // out param
            query.setString("PARAM2"), "SOME_VALUE"); // in param
            query.execute();
            String value = query.getString("PARAM1"); //outparam result
            System.out.println(value);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
           //process exception here
        }
    });
```