# How do I call a user defined sql function from springboot?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot

I'm trying to call a user defined function from PLSQL database, it
takes several variables and return a single float.

I've tried code like this:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT package.function("variables: 
value")
float getFuction(@Param("value") String value);
```

This shows an error saying "FROM keyword was not found where expected.

Comment: Maybe you need add ` from dual` Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867348/spring-data-jpa-calling-oracle-function

Comment: yeah it works now, but why does it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it should be like that (i do not have chance to check):

```java
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT package.function(:value) FROM dual")
float getFuction(@Param("value") String value);
```

It is based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50328732/11733759)

Answer (score 0):

The solution:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT package.function("variables: value") FROM dual")
float getFuction(@Param("value") String value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice overview about this topic can be found here:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures