# getting error PLS-00221 is not a procedure or is undefined when calling a stored procedure in springboot jpa repository

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

please help me with this one. I have a very simple crud project with a student table in oracle DB(ID,name,age,email) in springboot and all i want to know is get a student with a method in the jpa repository that calls a stored procedured. when run the project i got an error PLS-00221 is not a procedure or is undefined.

```
--stored procedure
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
findstudentbyid
RETURN STUDENT%ROWTYPE
IS
estudiante STUDENT%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    INTO estudiante
    FROM STUDENT
    WHERE ID=1;     
    RETURN estudiante;
END findstudentbyid;
```

```
//Entity in sprongboot project
@Entity
@Table

@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
        name = "findstudentbyid",
        procedureName = "findstudentbyid"
    )
})

public class Student {
  
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)

    //Private variables
    
    private Long ID;
    private String name;
    private Number age;
    private String email; 

    //Constructor
    protected Student(){}

    public Student(String name , Number age , String email){        
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.email = email;
    }



    public Long getID() {
        return ID;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public Number getAge() {
        return age;
    }
 
    
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

 
       
}
```

```
//JPA CRUD REPOSITORY
public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student,Long>{
    @Procedure(name = "findstudentbyid")
    Iterable<Student> findstudentbyid();
}
```

Comment: I don't know Java, but: I see that you enclosed function name into double quotes (can't tell, maybe Java expects that). In Oracle, object names are by default in UPPERCASE, unless created in mixed case and enclosed into double quotes. As you didn't do that - which is OK; don't use mixed case in Oracle - another option is to try with function call in uppercase. So: instead of `"findstudentbyid"`, try `"FINDSTUDENTBYID"`.

Answer (score 0):

You create a function but not a stored procedure.
These objects are different for DB and JPA, try to change your `create function` to `create procedure` or change the procedure's call to the function's call signature.
Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867348/spring-data-jpa-calling-oracle-function) for more info about JPA and function call.

Comment: i think it would be the same because either functions or procedures are stored in procedures folder in oracle. i already tried with native @query alternative but got the same error. thanks anyway.