# How to correctly call a stored function with return value in Oracle via Java JPA (Hibernate)?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures

We have to refracgtor some code used for integration with another application which runs in Oracle DB and exposes to us some stored procedures or functions. Actually the execution of those stored procedures is done via `Session` of Hibernate but for some security issues we are required to strictly use the generic JPA interfaces and `EntityManager`.
Unfortunately, we are facing some problems because we are not able to understand which is the right way to proceed. This is the signature of the Oracle stored function which is **inside a package**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE package body DEVELOPERS.INTEGRATION_OPERATIONS is
...
function doOperation(arg1_in    in number,
                     arg2_in    in varchar2,
                     arg3_in    in date,
                     arg4_in    in number,
                     arg5_in    in number,
                     arg6_in    in date,
                     arg7_in    in varchar2 default null,
                     arg8_in    in varchar2 default null,
                     arg9_in    in varchar2 default null,
                     arg10_in   in varchar2,
                     arg11_in   in number default null,
                     arg12_in   in number
                 ) return number is
...
end doOperation;
begin


...
end INTEGRATION_OPERATIONS;
```

The first trial I did was to use JPA `StoredProcedureQuery` by reading what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572626/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-from-java-and-jpa) and other similar posts. But it does not seem to work: it fails with an error saying that the procedure is not defined. My guess is that it expects a really stored procedure while mine is a function.
The only way which seems to work is the following:

```
public enum OPERATION_PARAMATERS {
    
    PARAM_ARG1(1,"arg1_in", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN),
    PARAM_ARG2(2, "arg2_in", String.class, ParameterMode.IN),
    PARAM_ARG3(3, "arg3_in", Timestamp.class, ParameterMode.IN),
    PARAM_ARG4(4, "arg4_in", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN),
    PARAM_ARG5(5, "arg5_in", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN),
    PARAM_ARG6(6, "arg6_in", Timestamp.class, ParameterMode.IN),
    PARAM_ARG7(7, "arg7_in", String.class, ParameterMode.IN),
    PARAM_ARG8(8, "arg8_in", String.class, ParameterMode.IN),
    PARAM_ARG9(9, "arg9_in", String.class, ParameterMode.IN),
    PARAM_ARG10(10, "arg10", String.class, ParameterMode.IN),
    PARAM_ARG11(11, "arg11_in", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN),
    PARAM_ARG12(12, "arg12_in", Long.class, ParameterMode.IN);

    private final int paramPosition;
    private final String paramName;
    private final Class<?> paramType;
    private final ParameterMode paramMode;
    
    <T> OPERATION_PARAMATERS(int paramPosition, String paramName, Class<T> clazz, ParameterMode paramMode) {
        this.paramPosition = paramPosition;
        this.paramName = paramName;
        this.paramType = clazz;
        this.paramMode = paramMode;
    }

    public int getParamPosition() {
        return paramPosition;
    }

    public String getParamName() {
        return paramName;
    }

    public Class<?> getParamType() {
        return paramType;
    }

    public ParameterMode getParamMode() {
        return paramMode;
    }
}


@Override
public void invokeOperation(final DoOperation operation) {
    
    Query nativeQuery = this.entityManager.createNativeQuery(DoOperation.STORED_FUNCTION_CALL);
    for(OPERATION_PARAMATERS p : OPERATION_PARAMATERS.values()) {
        nativeQuery.setParameter(p.getParamName(), operation.getParamValue(p));
    }
    nativeQuery.executeUpdate();
}
```

where `DoOperation` is a sort of DTO containing all values for parameters and the native query is

```
public static final String STORED_FUNCTION_CALL = "DECLARE res NUMBER; begin res \\:= INTEGRATION_OPERATIONS.DOOPERATION(:arg1_in, :arg2_in, :arg3_in, :arg4_in, :arg5_in, :arg6_in, :arg7_in, :arg8_in, :arg9_in, :arg10_in, :arg11_in, :arg12_in); END;";
```

This seems to be executed without errors, but supposing this is the right way to do, how can I recover the returned value in `res` variable? I cannot ask the other developers to refactor this function as a stored procedure with in/out paramaters as it is a legacy integration.
How can I do? Is there a way to use JPA `StoredProcedureQuery` or is it reserved to pure stored procedures?

Our application is a Java EE 7 application running under Wildfly 10 with EJB 3.1. The implementation of JPA is provided by Wildfly with hibernate-core-4.1.2.Final.jar

Comment: Checkout the documentation: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-sp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a custom Oracle function returning a value from JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989263/how-to-call-a-custom-oracle-function-returning-a-value-from-jpa)

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: what you linked me is Hibernate specific. I need to use JPA interfaces

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: I am afraid it does not. The stored function performs some DML in the tables, and Oracle complains that you cannot invoke a stored funtion which modifies data with a SELECT statement

Comment: There is no JPA way to call Stored Procedures!

Comment: There is, it is not simple to understand what to use and how

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Generally, there is a way to call stored procedures from JPA [look here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures). However, the issue seems to be related to oracle functions. It should be possible to use a `native query` regardless though

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Maybe no way was a bit to hard. I would say no typesafe usable way