# JAVA: ORA-06550: wrong number or types of arguments when calling procedure in jpa repository

Tags: oracle, jpa, procedure

I have, inside a package named PCK_STO, a stored procedure that return a value

the stored is

```
FUNCTION Storicizza ( pIdAccred       IN  acc0000_accreditamenti.id%TYPE
                    , pUser           IN  acc0000_accreditamenti.ins_user%TYPE
                    , pCognomeNome    IN  acc0000_accreditamenti.ins_cognome_nome%TYPE
                    , pCodiceFiscale  IN  acc0000_accreditamenti.ins_codice_fiscale%TYPE
                    , pVersione       IN  acc0000_accreditamenti.versione%TYPE
                    ) RETURN acc0000_accreditamenti.id%TYPE IS
  nIdKeyTranslate   act0001_key_translate.id%TYPE;
  recAccredit       acc0000_accreditamenti%ROWTYPE;
  nIdAccredTarget   acc0000_accreditamenti.id%TYPE;
  nIdNew            NUMERIC(10);
  nIdSedeNew        acc0107_sedi.id%TYPE;
BEGIN
..........

  RETURN nIdAccredTarget;
END;
```

I'm trying to call it in a jpa repository this way

```
@Procedure(value = "PCK_STO.Storicizza", outputParameterName = "nIdAccredTarget")
Long storicizza(@Param("pIdAccred") Long idAccreditamento, @Param("pUser") String user, @Param("pCognomeNome") String nomeCognome, @Param("pCodiceFiscale") String codFiscale, @Param("pVersione") Long versione);
```

I'm always getting the following error

```
Error : 6550, Position : 6, Sql = BEGIN PCK_STO.Storicizza(PIDACCRED=>:0,PUSER=>:1,PCOGNOMENOME=>:2,PCODICEFISCALE=>:3,PVERSIONE=>:4,NIDACCREDTARGET=>:5); END;, OriginalSql = {call PCK_STO.Storicizza(?,?,?,?,?,?)}, Error Msg = ORA-06550: row 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'STORICIZZA'
ORA-06550: row 1, colums 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: You call some object in the Oracle by @Procedure syntax. But, actually this is not procedure, this is function. Maybe this one will be usefull? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6989263/how-to-call-a-custom-oracle-function-returning-a-value-from-jpa

Comment: You'll need to bind to the return value of the function.