# Calling Oracle function with StoredProcedureQuery?

Tags: java, jpa, plsql, oracle11g, eclipselink

I'm trying to call an Oracle PL/SQL function using [javax.persistence.StoredProcedureQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/StoredProcedureQuery.html) and I get the error `PLS-00221: 'function_name' is not a procedure or is undefined`

So I assume its not possible to call an Oracle function using [StoredProcedureQuery](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/StoredProcedureQuery.html)?

I don't see JPA offering an interface to call functions(as opposed to stored procedures). So how do I accomplish it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling an oracle function from JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688152/calling-an-oracle-function-from-jpa)

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14722588/599528)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*As an addition to ukchaudhary's answer:*

> So I assume its not possible to call an Oracle function using
> StoredProcedureQuery?

Yes, exactly. Oracle has both *stored procedures* and *functions*.
`StoredProcedureQuery` can be used to call stored procedures, but it cannot call stored functions, at least not on Oracle (hence the name).

To call a function, JPA offers the `FUNCTION` keyword in JPA. This allows invoking a function from inside a JPQL query. For example, a function "hasGoodCredit" is called like this:

```
SELECT c FROM Customer c
WHERE FUNCTION(‘hasGoodCredit’, c.balance, c.creditLimit)
```

See JPA specification, [Invocation of Predefined and User-defined Database Functions](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.0/jakarta-persistence-spec-3.0.html#a5311).

However, `FUNCTION` only works inside a regular JPQL statement (SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE etc.), so it cannot be used for Oracle functions which perform data manipulation (DML), as these can only be invoked separately.

Therefore, such functions cannot be invoked via JPA. You will have to use JDBC or a native query.

Comment: @Roland: Hey - a question almost ten years old, and my answer is accepted within hours. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

**Sample Oracle Function:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_get_random_number
  RETURN NUMBER
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN TRUNC(dbms_random.value(1,100));
END;
```

**Solution 1: using SQL Query**

```
BigDecimal val = (BigDecimal)entityManager
                    .createNativeQuery("SELECT f_get_random_number FROM DUAL")
                    .getSingleResult();
```

**Solution 2: using JDBC API**

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap( Session.class );         
    Integer out = session.doReturningWork( 
        connection -> {
        try (CallableStatement function = connection.prepareCall("{ ? = call f_get_random_number }" )) {
            function.registerOutParameter( 1, Types.INTEGER );
            function.execute();
            return function.getInt(1);
        } 
    } );
```

Comment: Yes you can execute an SQL query that will call the function. But I'm looking for a way to call the function directly, as you can do with stored procedures.

Comment: It can be achieved through JDBC API as shown in solution 2.