# Call Oracle function with StoredProcedureQuery

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, function, jpa-2.1

Based on [Callable statement support](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/CallableStatementSupport) and many others docs javax.persistence.StoredProcedureQuery is presented in jpa 2.1 to

> standardized support for dealing with JDBC CallableStatements (stored procedure and function calls)

but when try to call an oracle function with an instance of StoredProcedureQuery the result always is

```
PLS-00221: 'function_name' is not a procedure or is undefined
```

This code is how i use it:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("function_name");

query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("param1", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("param2", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("param3", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
query.setParameter("param1", "will");
query.setParameter("param2", "smith");
query.execute();
Object param3 = query.getOutputParameterValue("param3");
```

The declaration of my function is like this:

```
function "function_name"(
      param1 in varchar2, param2 in varchar2, param3 out varchar2
   ) return number  is
```

So what is the matter with it.

Comment: What does the declaration of `function_name` look like?

Comment: It seems that it's not possible to call functions using pure JPA. Some people achieve it using a `SELECT F(X) FROM DUAL` query. That won't work in your case as you have an output parameter. Some people revert to native (SQL) statements. In your case, you could rewrite (or wrap) the function as a stored procedure with a second OUT parameter instead of the return value.

Comment: As @Codo states, that is really not a good practice to have a function return an out parameter.

Comment: The problem is I am using another team functions and they are designed like this and I have to use them like this.
Bottom line ,as @Codo said, is wrapping theirs function with my own procedures and call my own procedures.
Any way thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Oracle Function can be accessed through plain JDBC API.
check the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649326/calling-oracle-function-with-storedprocedurequery?answertab=active#tab-top).