# JPA Hibernate calling stored procedure

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, stored-procedures, jpa

I have a stored procedure in Postgres. That procedure has 4 OUT parameters. Using JPA normally I can't get the results. What I'm trying to do is use a SELECT query with that procedure.

For example If I try in pgAdmin the query:

SELECT * FROM get_results (arg0, arg1 etc);

I get one result row containing 4 columns with the results from the 4 OUT parameters.

But When I try to use it in JPA it fails. I'm trying something like:

```
Query q = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM get_results (arg0, arg1 etc)");
q.getSingleResult();
```

But it throws an `java.lang.IllegalStateException [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.nosuchtx] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.nosuchtx] No such transaction!`

Any suggestions?

Comment: The error message points to a transaction problem. Do other native queries (like selecting from a table) work at that place?

Comment: I tried the same query with count.
    em.createNativeQuery("SELECT count(*) FROM get_results (arg0, arg1 etc)"); q.getSingleResult();

and I get the number "1" as a result which is what I was expecting. So it works. But now when I try the normal query I get a :

"[ConnectionManager] forcing batcher resource cleanup on transaction completion; forgot to close ScrollableResults/Iterato r?"  Error.

Comment: You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572626/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-from-java-and-jpa/70788256#70788256), I hope it helps :
[How to call a stored procedure from Java and JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572626/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-from-java-and-jpa/70788256#70788256)

Answer (score 3):

JPA 2.1 now support Stored Procedure, read the Java doc [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#createStoredProcedureQuery%28java.lang.String%29).

Example:

```
StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("sales_tax");
// set parameters
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("subtotal", Double.class, ParameterMode.IN);
storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("tax", Double.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
storedProcedure.setParameter("subtotal", 1f);
// execute SP
storedProcedure.execute();
// get result
Double tax = (Double)storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("tax");
```

See detailed example [here](http://dreamand.me/java/java-jee7-jpa-stored-procedure-example/).

Answer (score 0):

use below code co call procedure using hibernate.

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("ProcedureName")
    .setParameter(parameterName,value);
    .setParameter(parameterName,value);
    .setParameter(parameterName,value);
    .setParameter(parameterName,value);
```

Comment: I can't use this code because as I said before my procedure has 4 OUT parameters. JPA works with only 1 OUT parameter. So the only way is the "Select * FROM procedure_name(...)".