# call stored procedure JPA 2.1 Repository with Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to call a stored procedure in MySQL call: "searchContext".

I have tried the solution : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10276048/jpa-hibernate-calling-stored-procedure) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572626/calling-stored-procedure-from-java-jpa)

But how can I get the EntityManager reference? If I'm using JPA Repositories like this:

```
public interface ActiveContextRepository extends JpaRepository<ActiveContext, Long> {
    ActiveContext findByIdUser(Integer idUser);     
}
```

I got null pointer when I use EntityManager like this:

```
public class ContextService {
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    public Integer getContext(Integer idUser, String date, Double longitude, Double latitude){
             StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("searchContext");
}
```

Or like this:

```
public class ContextService {

    @Autowired EntityManager entityManager;

    public Integer getContext(Integer idUser, String date, Double longitude, Double latitude){
                 StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("searchContext");
}
```

I also haved tried this solution:[here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/master/jpa/jpa21) 
 But precompiler gives me an error on the Jpa repository:

> "Invalid derived query!No property search found for a type
>   ActiveContext"

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? If not are you using XML configuration for beans or Java Configuration? Problem looks to be your entityManager bean not initialized.

Comment: Hell, You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572626/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-from-java-and-jpa/70788256#70788256), I hope it helps :
[How to call a stored procedure from Java and JPA SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572626/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-from-java-and-jpa/70788256#70788256)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem. I was making a "new() " of the class wich have the new entity manager...nie is injected with "autowire"  and bean is declared in application-config thank you