# JPA -SQL Server Stored Procedure ?

Tags: sql-server-2008, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures

In Sql server stored procedure i have insert statement while calling from **JPA** using below code :

```
em.createNativeQuery("{call dbo.sp_xxx(:v1,:v2)}");
finQuery.setParameter("v1", 123); 
finQuery.setParameter("v2", "durga");
finQuery.getResultList();
```

In my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_xxxx](
@v1 int,
@v2 nvarchar(10)
)
AS

BEGIN TRANSACTION   
BEGIN         

    INSERT INTO dbo.XXXX
           (v1,v2)
        VALUES
           (@v1,@v2)     
COMMIT TRANSACTION 
END
```

After executing the stored procedure

```
Exception sp_xxxx...javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query.
```

Iam able to run in sql server window.
Bur from **JPA**  iam getting above error.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572626/calling-stored-procedure-from-java-jpa?

Comment: we are able to get list . when we are using insert stmt in stored procedure. iam getiing above error.

Comment: sorry,didn't understand when you said `we are able to get list`? Do you mean the finQuery.getResultList() is returning you the list?

Comment: i dont need any result set. Iam using SP for inserting records. To execute that Stored Procedure, we used getResultlist. finQuery.getResultList(); . But iam getting above error while calling from JPA

Comment: instead of `getResultList()`, try `executeUpdate()` which would expect the SQL code to return update counts (the result of INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations). `getResultList()` would expect the SQL code to return result set (result of a SELECT operation).

Comment: cool, i moved it to the answer section :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of getResultList(), try executeUpdate() which would expect the SQL code to return update counts (the result of INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE operations). getResultList() would expect the SQL code to return result set (result of a SELECT operation)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code snippet. **Note**: I'm using SQL Server 2005 and OpenJPA

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("EXEC ps_GeneraSecuenciaClaveCentrales ?, ?, ? ");
query.setParameter(1, "VE");
query.setParameter(2, new Integer(48));
query.setParameter(3, new Integer(42));
String res = (String)query.getSingleResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
finQuery = em.createNativeQuery("exec sp_xxx :v1,:v2");
finQuery.setParameter("v1", 123);
finQuery.setParameter("v2", "durga");
finQuery.getResultList();
```