# Spring Autowire - Interface and Implementation DAO Class needed?

Tags: java, spring, interface, dao

First off, I have done some reading and I am wondering what is the purpose of having a Interface and the implementation class for example the Data Access Objects (DAO)? I have read that it increases flexibility, but I was wondering if someone could provide a concrete example as to why we need an interface.

If we are autowiring, do we still need to use a Interface and Implementation that implement the interface? If so, why? Do we just need the impl?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: @NathanHughes can Spring Data call SQL Package stored procedures? I am still wondering what the purpose of having an interface is for. So far it seems just like extra code to me.

Comment: yes, with JPA and JPQL. http://stackoverflow.com/q/3572626/217324

Comment: When you define an interface for your classes (maybe also for a DAO), it helps with dependency injection. If you want to inject another class that offers "equivalent" functionality, using an interface really helps.

You could have a DAO for different frameworks or different repository DB, and you could choose how inject.

@Nathan Hughes right, Spring Data provides the impl for you, but you can provide some implementation if you deemed necessary.

Comment: @Xstian: yes, i was overgeneralizing. you can provide your own custom impl. i haven't run into a case where i've had to do that yet, fortunately.

Comment: Alan, you have a point. @Autowired is really the antithesis of IOC and dependency injection as it locks you into a concrete implementation. Then why the interface? I'm with you in wondering at its applicability; you don't have to have an interface, you can Autowire an implemented class. Unless the interface is useful in some other capacity why do we use it?

Answer (score 1):

You don't strictly *need* an interface. But there are two reasons to prefer them:

- You can easily swap the implementation for testing purposes
- Proxy-ing beans for the purposes of aspect oriented programming or similar is
  easier (Java supports it out of the box)

Other reasons might be added, but these are the main 2 in my opinion. Still, don't feel forced to work like that. If the case you're working on does not warrant this flexibility, there's no need to complicate things.

And, by all means, [never call your classes *Impl](http://geekswithblogs.net/brian.johnston.blog/archive/2006/07/04/84054.aspx). If you can not come up with a proper name for the implementation, it means you shouldn't be having an interface to begin with.