# Error with JPA transaction when calling a stored procedure

Tags: oracle, jpa, transactions, ejb-3.0

I have a stored procedure in an Oracle DB, which I wish to call from my EJB AS (websphere) using the following JPA code.
The procedure includes some "COMMIT" in its body. The point is that when I remove the COMMIT of the procedure, JPA is able to invoque the procedure correctly. If I leave the COMMIT then I get an exception telling me that the call cannot be executed.

The java code is placed in a session bean with the transaction set up as REQUIRED by default.

```
    public void updateProc() {
       Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("call UPDATE_MYPROC()");
       query.executeUpdate();
    }
```

I think the problem has to do with the transaction, but not sure. Can anybody help? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, problem is in transactions. What locking mode are you using?

Comment: And look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572626/calling-stored-procedure-from-java-jpa)

Comment: If you don't want to remove COMMIT from the procedure, try to set NOT_SUPPORTED for the method in the session bean.

Comment: With NOT_SUPPORTED I get the same problem: 
ora-02089 commit is not allowed in a subordinate session

Comment: Is it possible to not use XA Datasourse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the container to manage persistence. By using transaction REQUIRED, JPA will start a new transaction for each call to the database.  Therefore it's not necessary to start or commit a transaction within the stored procedure.  In fact, it's a bad idea.

You don't mention if you start a new transaction in the stored procedure, just that you have a commit in there.  If you don't start a (new) transaction, that commit will cause problems. Even if you do, it's unnecessary, this is the sort of stuff we use JPA for to start with.