# Sample Java Program to call Teradata Stored Procedure

Tags: java, teradata, java-stored-procedures

I want to call Teradata store procedure from Java program, Can anyone have the sample java program ?

Due to some restriction,I couldn't create some UDF functions inside Teradata, so I developed those function as stored procedure in Teradata.

Now, I need to call those procedures using Java Program.

Friends, These is my java program,

```
public static String executeme(String x,String y) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
 {
     System.out.println(" Message: 2 " );
     String connectionString = "jdbc:teradata://192.168.0.0/xyz,tmode=ANSI,charset=UTF8,DBS_PORT=1025,DATABASE=xyz";
     String user = "xyz";
     String passwd = "xxx";
     System.out.println(" Message: 3 after url " +x );
     String sCall = "{CALL "+x+"(?,?)}";
     System.out.println(" Message: after call str " +sCall );
     String result = null;

     try
     {
         Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");

         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, user, passwd);  
         System.out.println(" Message: after con "+con  );
         CallableStatement cStmt = con.prepareCall(sCall);
         cStmt.setString(1, y);
         cStmt.registerOutParameter(2, Types.VARCHAR);          
         result = cStmt.getString(2);   

         return result;  


     }       
     catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
     {
         System.out.println(" Message: " + e);
         return e.toString();    
     }



 }
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String outs=null; 
    System.out.println(" Message: 1 " );
    outs = testing.executeme("sample_name", "ABCD");
     System.out.println(outs);
}
```

But, while running this program, i'm getting as error:

```
Message: 1 
Message: 2 
Message: 3 after url ment_f_swithin
Message: after con com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection@85ede7b
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 14.10.00.42] [Error 5510] [SQLState HY000] Invalid session mode for   procedure execution.
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDatabaseSQLException  (ErrorFactory.java:308)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.ReceiveInitSubState.action(ReceiveInitSubState.java:109)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.subStateMachine(StatementReceiveState.java:307)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.action(StatementReceiveState.java:196)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.runBody(StatementController.java:123)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.run(StatementController.java:114)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:386)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.prepareRequest(TDStatement.java:573)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDPreparedStatement.<init>(TDPreparedStatement.java:117)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_PreparedStatement.<init>(JDK6_SQL_PreparedStatement.java:29)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_CallableStatement.<init>(JDK6_SQL_CallableStatement.java:23)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdk6.JDK6_SQL_Connection.constructCallableStatement(JDK6_SQL_Connection.java:87)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.prepareCall(TDSession.java:1373)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.prepareCall(TDSession.java:1408)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDSession.prepareCall(TDSession.java:1394)
at java_func.testing.executeme(testing.java:32)
at java_func.testing.main(testing.java:55)
```

I tried using all the 3 modes ANSI,TERA,BTET. but still i'm getting the same error, kindly guide me please

Comment: Where is your code sample? Please paste it to get help.

Comment: Did you read the online docu? https://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samplePrograms.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling stored procedure from Java / JPA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572626/calling-stored-procedure-from-java-jpa)

Answer (score 0):

```
Connection conn1;

<... connect conn1 ...>

conn1.createStatement().execute("call proc_test()");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just instead of this line:

```
String connectionString = "jdbc:teradata://192.168.0.0/xyz,tmode=ANSI,charset=UTF8,DBS_PORT=1025,DATABASE=xyz";
```

I changed into

```
String connectionString = "jdbc:teradata://192.168.0.0/tmode=ANSI,charset=UTF8";
```