# Unable to set value in Datamodel class in java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
public CommonResponseModel getLeaveHistory(HttpHeaders httpHeaders) {

        EntityManager manager = DBManager.getDBManager();
        int empId = Integer.parseInt(httpHeaders.getHeaderString(AppConstants.Headers.EMP_ID));
        StoredProcedureQuery appliedhistory = manager.createStoredProcedureQuery("leave_applied_history_SP",
                "appliedhistory");
        appliedhistory.registerStoredProcedureParameter("employeeid", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        StoredProcedureQuery historyleavehistory = manager.createStoredProcedureQuery("Leave_history_SP",
                "historyleavehistory");
        StoredProcedureQuery mangerquery = manager.createStoredProcedureQuery("testformanger", "manger");
        mangerquery.registerStoredProcedureParameter("employeeid", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        historyleavehistory.registerStoredProcedureParameter("employeeid", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        appliedhistory.setParameter("employeeid", 845);
        historyleavehistory.setParameter("employeeid", 845);
        mangerquery.setParameter("employeeid", 845);            
        List<AppliedLeaveHistoryModel> appliedleavehistory = appliedhistory.getResultList();
        AppliedLeaveHistoryModel applied = new AppliedLeaveHistoryModel();
        List<Managers> mangerlist = mangerquery.getResultList();
        List<HistoryLeaveHistoryModel> hitoryleavehistory = historyleavehistory.getResultList();
        applied.setManager(mangerlist);
        LeaveHistoryResponseWrapper model = new LeaveHistoryResponseWrapper();
        LeaveHistoryData leavehistorydata = new LeaveHistoryData();
        leavehistorydata.setApplied(appliedleavehistory);
        leavehistorydata.setHistory(hitoryleavehistory);
        model.setData(leavehistorydata);
        return model;

    }
```

this is my Datamodel:

```
public class AppliedLeaveHistoryModel {
    int leaveId;
    String type;
    Date appliedOn;
    String dates;
    String reason;
    int days;
    int approvalStatus;
    List<Managers> manager;

    public List<Managers> getManager() {
        return manager;
    }

    public void setManager(List<Managers> manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

    public AppliedLeaveHistoryModel() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public AppliedLeaveHistoryModel(int leaveId, String type, Date appliedOn, String dates, String reason, int days,
            int approvalStatus) {
        this.leaveId = leaveId;
        this.type = type;
        this.appliedOn = appliedOn;
        this.dates = dates;
        this.reason = reason;
        this.days = days;
        this.approvalStatus = approvalStatus;

    }

    public int getLeaveId() {
        return leaveId;
    }

    public void setLeaveId(int leaveId) {
        this.leaveId = leaveId;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Date getAppliedOn() {
        return appliedOn;
    }

    public void setAppliedOn(Date appliedOn) {
        this.appliedOn = appliedOn;
    }

    public String getDates() {
        return dates;
    }

    public void setDates(String dates) {
        this.dates = dates;
    }

    public String getReason() {
        return reason;
    }

    public void setReason(String reason) {
        this.reason = reason;
    }

    public int getDays() {
        return days;
    }

    public void setDays(int days) {
        this.days = days;
    }

    public int getApprovalStatus() {
        return approvalStatus;
    }

    public void setApprovalStatus(int approvalStatus) {
        this.approvalStatus = approvalStatus;
    }

}
```

I am getting Data from List listmanger and I have created AppliedLeaveHistoryModel object and am able to set object.setManger(listmanger) but when I debug and check the value of List appliedleavehistory = appliedhistory.getResultList(); in this object I am unable to set that value. Please help me where am doing wrong .

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19107545/2586617) answer.