# Call a stored procedure from Java using Entity Manager

Tags: java, sql, stored-procedures, parameters, entity

guys! I want to call a procedure in SQL from Java, that sets some date limits. I am currently using EntityManager.

This is what I have done so far:

```
public void setInterval(){
        Query query = e.createNativeQuery("Declare "
                + "dStartDate date :=  ADD_MONTHS( sysdate, - 60);"
                + "begin "
                + "scheme.setLimits( dStartDate, ADD_MONTHS( sysdate, - 1));"
                + ":END := To_Char(SYSDATE,'yyyy/mm');"
                + ":START := To_Char(dStartDate,'yyyy/mm');" + "end;");
        query.setParameter("END", new String()).setParameter("START", new String());
    }
```

I am not sure how should I set the parameters to call this procedure. The date is set through SQL so I should just declare the out parameters. The query does also not return any result set. Some ideas ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello Please try like below
 Query query = e.createNativeQuery("Your Query");
 q.setParameter("END", new String());
 q.setParameter("START", new String());
 List results= query.getResultList();

Comment: that is exactly what I tried but it's not working. Actually my query does not return a result set

Comment: Can you check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572626/calling-stored-procedure-from-java-jpa