# Sending params to a stored procedure in JPA

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in Oracle DB which takes in an user-defined object as input. Any inputs on how to invoke this stored procedure in JPA?

User defined object :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE TEST AS OBJECT 
(
     NAME varchar2(200),
     AGE number(10,2)
)
```

Stored procedure package :

```
create or replace PACKAGE TRIAL_PACKAGE 
AS TYPE REC IS RECORD(NAME VARCHAR2(200),AGE NUMBER(10,2));
    PROCEDURE TEST_PACK(r IN REC);
END TRIAL_PACKAGE; 

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY TRIAL_PACKAGE AS
    PROCEDURE TEST_PACK(r IN REC) AS
    BEGIN
        -- TODO: Implementation required for PROCEDURE TRIAL_PACKAGE.TEST_PACK

        INSERT INTO TABLE_TEST1(NAMES, AGE) 
        VALUES(r.NAME, r.AGE);
    END ;
END TRIAL_PACKAGE;
```

Comment: Please refer to this Question Hope it answers your Query [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572626/calling-stored-procedure-from-java-jpa)

Comment: The input type should be an object not an int,string etc