# How to call a PL/SQL stored procedure in SPRING BOOT JPA by passing Array of objects

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

AM trying call a PL/SQL stored procedure in SPRING BOOT JPA by passing Array of objects.

example

```
PACKAGE.upload_raw_data (
      p_i_raw_dtls     IN     XX_DTLS_TB,
      p_i_file_id         IN     NUMBER,
      p_o_error_code         OUT VARCHAR2,
      p_o_error_message      OUT VARCHAR2)

Table Type: XX_DTLS_TB is of Object Type: XX_DTLS_OBJ

XX_DTLS_OBJ Object Attributes:

ADDRESS VARCHAR2 (4000),
CITY VARCHAR2 (300),
PROV VARCHAR2 (300)
PORT VARCHAR2 (300)
VENDORNAME VARCHAR2 (300),
VENDCODE VARCHAR2 (300),
CTRYOFORIGIN VARCHAR2 (300),
PLACEOFEXPORT VARCHAR2 (300),
TTCODE VARCHAR2 (300),
REGION VARCHAR2 (300),
BROKER_NAME VARCHAR2 (300)
```

How can i call this Stored procedure

Comment: Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572626/calling-stored-procedure-from-java-jpa

Comment: Hey Vivek, Thanks for the link, but in all the examples posted there the input param are always singe i.e either String, Long etc... none of them is ARRAY LIST of objects for my req I need to pass ARRAY LIST of OBJECTS. Kindly help here