# Call stored procedures with array list as input parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, plsql, oracle11g, spring-data-jpa

I've a requirement to call oracle stored procedures with array list as input parameter using spring Jpa. Can anyone please mention if this is feasible using Spring Boot. What are the possible ways that can be followed to achieve the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call a stored procedure from Java and JPA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572626/how-to-call-a-stored-procedure-from-java-and-jpa)